# When to and when not to define a default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

What are the rules wether to define a default constructor for myClass or not?

Example: the user defined type Book(which could have title, author, ISBN and genre as its datamembers) should probably have no default constructor, since there is no "default book".

Is there some guide which handles this topic?

Comment: Nothing but normal sense. You define an explicit default ctor if you need additional processing, and you mark it as deleted if you want to prevent it to be used. Beware a class with an explicitely deleted or private ctor will be harder to use in containers...

Answer (score 1):

If you reasonably can, make your type [regular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular). That means you should support:

- default construction
- copy construction
- assignment
- equality comparision

That only requires *defining* `==` and ensuring that default construction is still available.